# School of thought puts pin in charged oxygen atom

Tags: cryptic-clues

Here's another Cryptic Clue I came up with:

> School of thought puts pin in charged oxygen atom (7)

Hope you like it!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my opinion the intended answer here is...

> **OPINION**!

Explanation:

> The definition is 'school of thought', and the wordplay requires placing PIN in "O ION" (charged oxygen atom, since oxygen's symbol is 'O' and a charged atom is an 'ION').